# Замена последней запятой на точку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как прописать регулярное выражение, чтобы заменяло именно **последнюю запятую** на **точку**?

```
usr7.replace(/,/, '.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
usr7.replace(/,$/, '.');
```

> `$`  - значит что образец должен быть в конце строки или, если это многострочный  текст в конце одной из строк

Comment: @Rules, благодарю!

Comment: @Руслан Дуров Спасибо за репутацию :)

Comment: а если последняя запятая стоит самым первым символом в строке?

Answer (score 5):

Последняя запятая меняется так:

```
text.replace(/,(?![^,]*,)/m, '.');
```